# Find largest of numbers - Beginner Java

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop

Task is to read a set of positive values & report their maximum after the user enters a negative value. Extend to minimum.
I think the problem in this is that the variable max is initialised as 0. Afterwards it remains in the while loop only, so the output is always 0. 
I dont know how to bring the last max value out of loop and print it. 
Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;


  // constants

  // variables
  int input;
  int max = 0;
  int a = 0;
  // program code
  System.out.println( "Input the numeber: "); input = scan.nextInt();

  if ( input < 0 ) {
    System.out.println( "You did not enter any positive number " );
  }
  else {
    while ( input >= 0 ) {

      input = a;
      if ( a >= input) {
        a = max;
      }
      else {
        input = max;
      }
      input = scan.nextInt();
      }
  }
  System.out.println( max );

  }

  // todo...


}
```

Comment: There are a lot of logic errors. You should review the whole code, the problem does not lie in just a few lines but all of them

Comment: There is a lot to say about your code. How many numbers will the user input? When does the inputting stop? Why care if the number is positive/negative?

Comment: please format nicely .... `System.out.println( "Input the numeber: "); input = scan.nextInt();`  --- put code on sep. lines

Comment: @Barakmanos I know the code is far from perfect, but try sounding less insulting :/

Comment: Dici is right. This program is wrong on too many levels. Try to consider: what is the purpose of `a`, `max` and `input`? Use either a debugger or just pen and paper, and try to run a few loops, note the values of the variables, and think if this is what you expected them to do.

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc: Sorry, didn't mean to insult anyone. It's not about how the code looks. It's about the fact that one cannot point out the problem, as the entire logic is wrong (let alone the use of `=`).

Answer (score 3):

Problem in your code :

1. you are not assigning `input` value to `max` anywhere.
2. `input = a; // each time you are assigning a to input so input becomes 0 since a is 0.`
3. `if ( a >= input) {   // this condition will be always true
       a = max;
   }`

concept is simple :

step 1. initialize `max` to 0

step 2. repeat `while input >=0`

step 3. check `if input > max` then set `max=input`

setp 4. print `max`.

code this given below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
        int input;
        int max = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input the numeber: ");
        input = scan.nextInt();
        if (input < 0) {
            System.out.println("You did not enter any positive number ");
        }
        else {
            while (input >= 0) {
                if (max < input) {
                    max = input;
                }
                input = scan.nextInt();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(max);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you!
Could you tell me why in my code, variable max was not getting out of the while loop?

Comment: Although this gives a solution, it doesn't explain the answer.  You should add an explanation (why yours works and why OP's doesn't).

Answer (score 0):

The code looks a bit iffy in general, may be some problems in there, but the basic logic/algorithm problem is max should be set the first number you are looking at not zero.

This is the classic scan for max value in a list technique. You want to maintain the invariant that max is always the maximum value you have encounter so far, so you can't set to an arbitrary value since that may not be in the list or greater than members of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You just have logical errors in maintaining max.  Rustam's answer is what you're looking for, but for clarification, you only need the maintained max and input coming in, and only update max when there is a new max and input when you're taking the input, no need for a at all.

Answer (score 0):

you can use :

```
 if (input < 0) {
              //----
     }else {
            while (input >= 0) {
                if (max < input) {
                    max = input;
                }
                input = scan.nextInt();
            }
     }
     System.out.println(max);
```

in your code you haven't set value to max!